# How to name the fields of a custom form in django?

Tags: django

I am creating a custom from in django.

```
class MeasurementsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    d_value=forms.IntegerField(help_text="insert the diabetes")
    class Meta:
        model=Measurements
        fields=('d_value',)
```

In the `fields=('d_value',)`, do I need match the name of the fields with the name of fields of the model? Whenever I ran this I got form name as D value instead of d_value. What is the problem?

What is the function of this line   `d_value=forms.IntegerField(help_text="insert the diabetes")`. Is it mandatory to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the name in `fields` is the name of the field like you named it in the model, so `d_value`.

The [**`help_text=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#help-text) parameter is used to add extra hints. These will, if you construct a `ModelForm`, typically popup when you hover over the item, although that depends on how you render the form.

You can change the name the field shows in the `ModelForm` by altering the [**`verbose_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#verbose-name):

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    d_value=forms.IntegerField(
        verbose_name='Diabetes value',
        help_text='insert the diabetes'
    )
```

Or if you want to make a different label for a specific form, you can specify that with a [**`labels=…`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) the `Meta` of the `ModelForm`:

```
class MeasurementsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Measurements
        fields=('d_value',)
        labels = {
            'd_value': 'Other label for d_value'
        }
```

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Measurement` instead of <s>`Measurements`</s>.

Answer (score 2):

In the `fields` attribute of the Meta class you add all the fields of your model that you want to add to the form.

If you need to add some fields that doesn't exist in your model, you just add them as fields of your form (like `d_value`) and you haven't to add them to the fields attribute.

"do i need match the name of the fields with the name of fields of the model?":

Yes, the names should match if you want to match a model field with a form field